# Python, Stripe, get Card id from Source

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm retrieving sources of customer by its own id.

In source there is type called `card`.

Is it possible to get Card id from Customer's Source?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources

Comment: @MrE I know about this API. However, inside source there is no Card id.

Comment: the cards API lets you list all cards for a given customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/list

> List all cards You can see a list of the cards belonging to a
>   customer. Note that the 10 most recent sources are always available on
>   the Customer object. If you need more than those 10, you can use this
>   API method and the limit and starting_after parameters to page through
>   additional cards.